# regex to allow only numbers and comma in C#

Tags: c#

I am using regex ISMatch method to check that string contains only numbers and comma and accept below two types

EX-> 123,456  Accepted

EX-> 123,456, Accepted

I am using below regex but it does not works it pass string with alphabets too

```
[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*,?
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: "does not works" is the _least_ specific description of what happens.

Comment: Define `does not works`

Comment: It allows string with alphabets too.

Comment: @Mayank Try putting anchors on both ends `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end.

Comment: A place worth a visit is https://regex101.com/. It allows you to test you regex expressions. It is missing a C# setting, but in most cases it is identical to e.g. PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest regex:

```
^\d*[,]\d*$
```

However, this will succeed for just , with no digits. If you require at least one digit either before or after the comma or dot, I think this is it:

```
^(\d+[,]\d*|\d*[,]\d+)$
```

If the comma is optional rather than required, add ? after [,].

Comment: In C# it is better to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, because `\d` matches non-ASCII digits, like `०, १, २, ३, ४, ५, ६, ७, ८, ९`

Comment: Does not work in C# (also tested on regex101).  This does: ^[\d,]*\d$